# How to install additional packages in sagemaker pipeline

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I want to add dependency packages in my sagemaker pipeline which will be used in Preprocess step.

I have tried to add it in `required_packages` in `setup.py` file but it's not working.
I think setup.py file is no use of at all.

```
required_packages = ["sagemaker==2.93.0", "matplotlib"]
```

Preprocessing steps:

```
sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
        framework_version="0.23-1",
        instance_type=processing_instance_type,
        instance_count=processing_instance_count,
        base_job_name=f"{base_job_prefix}/job-name",
        sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
        role=role,
    )
    step_args = sklearn_processor.run(
        outputs=[
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/validation"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
        ],
        code=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "preprocess.py"),
        arguments=["--input-data", input_data],
    )
    step_process = ProcessingStep(
        name="PreprocessSidData",
        step_args=step_args,
    )
```

Pipeline definition:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
        name=pipeline_name,
        parameters=[
            processing_instance_type,
            processing_instance_count,
            training_instance_type,
            model_approval_status,
            input_data,
        ],
        steps=[step_process],
        sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    )
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for the preprocess step and pipeline definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each job within the pipeline you should have separate requirements (so you install only the stuff you need in each step and have full control over it).

To do this, you need to use the `source_dir` parameter:

> **source_dir** (str or PipelineVariable) – Path (absolute, relative or an
> S3 URI) to a directory with any other training source code
> dependencies aside from the entry point file (default: None). If
> source_dir is an S3 URI, it must point to a tar.gz file. Structure
> within this directory are preserved when training on Amazon SageMaker.

Look at the [documentation in general for Processing](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.FrameworkProcessor.run) (you have to use [FrameworkProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.FrameworkProcessor)).

Within the specified folder, there must be the script (in your case preprocess.py), any other files/modules that may be needed, and the `requirements.txt` file.

The structure of the folder then will be:

```
BASE_DIR/
|- requirements.txt
|- preprocess.py
```

It is the common requirements file, nothing different. And it will be used automatically at the start of the instance, without any instruction needed.

---

So, your code becomes:

```py
from sagemaker.processing import FrameworkProcessor
from sagemaker.sklearn import SKLearn
from sagemaker.workflow.steps import ProcessingStep
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput


sklearn_processor = FrameworkProcessor(
    estimator_cls=SKLearn,
    framework_version='0.23-1',
    instance_type=processing_instance_type,
    instance_count=processing_instance_count,
    base_job_name=f"{base_job_prefix}/job-name",
    sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    role=role
)

step_args = sklearn_processor.run(
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/validation"),
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
    ],
    code="preprocess.py",
    source_dir=BASE_DIR,
    arguments=["--input-data", input_data],
)

step_process = ProcessingStep(
    name="PreprocessSidData",
    step_args=step_args
)
```

Note that I changed both the `code` parameter and the `source_dir`. It's a good practice to keep the folders for the various steps separate so you have a requirements.txt for each and don't create overlaps.

Comment: it is showing error: TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source_dir'

Comment: Absolutely true! I remembered that SKLearnProcessor does not accept this parameter, but the generic FrameworkProcessor (which can be configured equally as SKLearnProcessor) does. I edited the answer by modifying the tested and working code.

Comment: i just checked this, it did not copy the requirements.txt with the source code. right now i am checking dependencies parameter of FrameworkProcessor.

Comment: it worked by adding `dependencies=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "requirements.txt")],` please add this in your answer.

Comment: It is very strange what you are saying, by specifying the source_dir, the latter will be copied entirely to the sourcedir.tar.gz (and thus including all the files that were inside including the requirements.txt). Look at this [official example](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.18.0/frameworks/tensorflow/using_tf.html#use-third-party-libraries) that specifies exactly what I'm telling you. I can add dependencies param to the answer, but the way I wrote you must also work (I use it daily)

Comment: that's what i wondering as well. it should have copied everything but it specifically omitted the requirements.txt and copied everything else.
and yes have used it with training scripts, but it was notw orking same way in processing step.

Comment: The sagemaker version needs to be investigated at this point. I see from the original question that you do not have the latest (2.117.0) but you have 2.93.0. I wonder if it is something recently introduced.

Comment: i will check that, thanks.

Comment: This is very informative and it is very similar to how [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551835/how-to-add-additional-files-in-sagemaker-pipeline-processing-step) are using `source_dir` to pass on multiple scripts. I am wondering if there is a way to do both and accommodate code shared across multiple Steps. eg. have `helper_functions.py` under BASE_DIR as well as multiple subfolders for each Step. Within each subfolder, have the corresponding code and a `requirements.txt` (implementing your answer). Is there a way to pass-in `helper_functions.py` and utilize `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I am getting this value error when I take sklearn_processor.run into step args and pass it as an argument in ProcessingStep. When I dont assign the sklearn_processor.run to any variable and just run it without assigning and pass estimator as sklearn_processor in ProcessingStep it works.

`ValueError: either step_args or processor need to be given, but not both.`

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to implement [Giuseppe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74598115/9205210) answer but the following is the only way I have gotten `requirements.txt` to work:

Folder structure:

```
parent_dir/
    requirements.txt
    pipelines/my_pipeline/
        pipeline.py
        step_processing.py
        preprocess.py
        helper_functions.py
```

Part of `step_processing.py`:

```
    sklearn_processor = FrameworkProcessor(
        estimator_cls=SKLearn,
        framework_version="0.23-1",
        instance_type=processing_instance_type,
        instance_count=processing_instance_count,
        base_job_name=base_job_name,
        sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
        role=role,
        )
    step_args = sklearn_processor.run(
        outputs=[
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="train", source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="validation", source="/opt/ml/processing/validation"),
            ProcessingOutput(output_name="test", source="/opt/ml/processing/test"),
        ],
        code='preprocess.py',
        arguments=["--input-data", input_data],
        source_dir=BASE_DIR,
        dependencies=['requirements.txt'],
        )
```

This implementation has allowed me to `import helper_functions` within `preprocess.py` which is a related [concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551835/how-to-add-additional-files-in-sagemaker-pipeline-processing-step/74552275#74552275).

If I could get Giuseppe's answer to work it would mean I can move `requirements.txt` and the preprocessing code into a subfolder within `my_pipeline/` which would be fantastic. However, at the moment I have only been successful by having `requirements.txt` directly under the parent directory.