# Running custom script as part of Sagemaker Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Exploring the Sagemaker Python SDK and trying to setup a minimal pipeline: A custom python script which reads two csv files from S3 folder, processes data and writes a single file back to S3. Can't seem to find any examples/documentation which explains this process.

1. Will having two input files (data/headers are different in each file) create problems?
2. What processor to use? Most examples seem to use SKLearnProcessor or PySparkProcessor. I don't use either of the frameworks. Just need to do some simple data processing using Pandas.
3. What is the use/need for ScriptProcessor? Do I need to use this for running a custom script?
4. How to pass on package dependencies? Most dependencies are open source packages but there are a couple of packages that are hosted on a private CodeArtifact repository.

Most of the examples found on the web seem to use either SKLearnProcessor or PySparkProcessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task can be solved with a simple processing job.

By using SKLearnProcessor, you already imply the use of a scikit-learn container. Otherwise, you can use a generic ScriptProcessor and specify the most appropriate container (already existing in sagemaker, such as that of scikit-learn or one of your own completely customised).

**Within the scikit-learn container, libraries such as pandas and numpy are already present.** You can look at the [complete list of requirements](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container/blob/master/requirements.txt) here.

Below is an example of code that answers the questions on file input/output from S3:

```py
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version=framework_version,  # e.g. "1.0-1", 
    role=role, 
    instance_type=your_instance_type,  # e.g. 'ml.m5.large'
    base_job_name = your_base_job_name,
    instance_count=your_instance_count,  # e.g. 1
)

sklearn_processor.run(
    code=your_script_path,
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(
            input_name='insert-custom-name-for-first-file',
            source=first_file_s3_uri,
            destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/data",
            s3_data_type='S3Prefix',
            s3_input_mode="File"
        ),
        ProcessingInput(
            input_name='insert-custom-name-for-second-file',
            source=second_file_s3_uri,
            destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/data",
            s3_data_type='S3Prefix',
            s3_input_mode="File"
        )
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(
            output_name="output-channel-name",
            destination=output_s3_path_uri,
            source="/opt/ml/processing/processed_data"
        )
    ]
)
```

*If both input files reside in the same folder on S3, you can directly load a single [ProcessingInput](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ProcessingInput) pointing to that folder instead of separating the two files. However, since they are only two, I recommend distinguishing them as I have done in the example.*

---

For dependencies: if they are modules to be loaded, you could pass them just like ProcessingInput. See the [run() documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.FrameworkProcessor.run) under `source_dir`, `dependencies` and `git_config`. That way you can choose the optimal configuration for your task.

---

In conclusion, using the sklearn container directly is not wrong. Install maybe something you don't need, but it's not a lot of stuff. If you have no particular need for compatibility with other libraries, use this ready-made container. Otherwise, go with a [custom container](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.html).

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe. This is really helpful. Surprised, Sagemaker doesn't have a built-in barebones container with just standard Python to run adhoc scripts and users are expected to create our own. While the process to create one might be trivial, added complexity writing/, executing and maintaining extra code/services. (Worth it only if you need a custom container).

Comment: Any doc/resources to understand pros/cons/need for separate ProcessingInput instances (tracking lineage?).

Comment: I am not aware of any documentation on this, but I think it is more a matter of clarity and cleanliness of the code to specify the inputs separately (when possible) rather than keeping them together. That way you have the possibility of tracking what you input already in the job definition. If you pass a folder directly, you don't have full control over what files you have passed. So it depends on the type of scenario you are in. I don't think there is any significant difference in terms of performance.

Comment: I really don't understand why there isn't a generic python container either, the containers are really inconsistent - for example the huggingface container allows you to pass a source dir and a script name as arguments. If the source dir containers `requirements.txt` it's installed, and you can also select which version of python to use. But the sklearn container doesn't so it's way easier to use the huggingface container - but that means you have to use a GPU instance. So I just make my own as it's easier